# How to show global header(array type) parameter in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I use springfox swagger ui of version 2.9.2. I want to display a header in all the APIs and I followed the example as shown [here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot). The example worked with header parameter of type String. However, I require a header parameter of type array of strings.

```java
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xyz"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
        .build()
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .globalOperationParameters(getParameters());
}

private List<Parameter> getParameters() {
    ParameterBuilder parameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
    List<Parameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();

    parameterList.clear();
    parameterBuilder.name("testHeader").modelRef(new ModelRef("String"))
        .allowMultiple(true).parameterType("header").required(true).build();
    parameterList.add(parameterBuilder.build());
    return parameterList;
}
```

How do I get a header of type array in UI? Right now this renders a single text box in UI for the `testHeader`.

Comment: Can you post the code where you have added annotation for header ?

Comment: I don't any header annotation. I have added the calling code in the question.